# How to make visible a div when hovering over <a> on another div

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `div` *visible*, when hovering over an `<a>` tag on another *div*. I tried using ***+***, ***>*** but none of them worked. Here is the relevant code I used.

### The CSS:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.dropdown-1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.main a:hover:first-child>.dropdown-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <a href="#">Shop Now <em class="fa fa-angle-down"></em></a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-1">
    <a href="#" id="c1">categories <em class="fa fa-angle-down"></em></a>
    <a href="#">New Arrivals</a>
    <a href="#">Trending Now</a>
    <a href="#">Sales & Offers</a>
    <a href="#">Gift Her</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-2">
    <a href="#">Frocks</a>
    <a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
    <a href="#">Sarees</a>
    <a href="#">Tops</a>
    <a href="#">Office Wear</a>
    <a href="#">Skirts</a>
    <a href="#">Salwar</a>
    <a href="#">Party Dresses</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make `.dropdown-1` ***visible***, when ***hovering*** over `<a>shop now<a>` which is in .main class. I tried using, `.main a:hover:first-child + .dropdown-1` but it didn't work. How to do this?

Comment: Given that you're talking about needing to select back _up_ the DOM tree, I'm relatively sure that you're limited to doing this with JS or with _very_ ugly CSS hacks-- *_or_*, maybe revisit your markup structure and see if you can find a better hierarchy-- since the content in `dropdown-1` is related to/triggered by the "Shop Now" anchor, perhaps they should be siblings or the dropdown should be a child of the container that holds the anchor...

Comment: Alex beat me to it, you could just restructure your drop down 1 and 2 elements and place them inside your MAIN element selector. Then you could use the general sibling selector ~ like `.main a:hover:first-child ~ .dropdown-1`. CSS => ***Cascading Style Sheets***, literally meaning it works from top down in the DOM tree, you just can't target up the DOM out of a parent element.